# What is the difference between Socket.IO and Firebase?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, firebase

I watched a codeschool tutorial on Node.js and they imitated a chat server using Socket.IO in their tutorial.

I am also under the impression that Firebase does the same thing.

What is the difference between the two, if there are any?

Comment: SocketIO is an opensource library.
Firebase is a cloud service.
Both of them use Websockets. But everyone has his own js layer implementation

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There actually is the difference.

Socket.io is a javascript library to manage sockets. In a web-chat example, you create sockets:

1. client(s) to server
2. Server to client(s)

That is, you control all the end-points, and use **socket.io** as a tool to communicate between your end-points.

In contrast, using firebase you only focus around **1** (client to server)

---

Pros and Cons of using service versus own infrastructure is a different subject, and heavily opinionated.

Comment: But can't you create a web-chat with firebase as well?

Comment: @user3587754 Yes, let me bring you an example. Imagine an oven (socket.io) and take-away pizza (firebase). Both will let you get an end-product - pizza (web-chat). Later is more expensive (because it is a service), but easier. Though, with oven (socket.io) you have more control, yet it comes with more responsibilities.

Comment: @alandarev what a beautiful explanation! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many differences. For example:

**SDKs**

Firebase has 9 SDKs, including JavaScript, Android, Unity.
Socket just 1 official client library (JavaScript) for browsers.

**Realtime Features**
Firebase has pub/sub messaging, connection state recovery, presence, native push notifications, webhooks.
Socket.io doesn't have any of those.

**Documentation**

Both have pretty good documentation with Getting Started Guides, Information Architecture and Developer Journey, API reference.

Those are just some examples, but here is an [in-depth comparison between Firebase and Socket.io](https://ably.com/compare/firebase-vs-socketio)